# Display each element of an array at different points on the line chart using callback

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js, tooltip

I have an array that stores the time in which the data was sent. I was trying to print each of the elements of the array, in the points that are in my chart, since the order of the dots in the chart is exactly the same as the time it was sent. But when I tried using a loop or something of that kind, It was looping for all of the other dots too, and I need the time to only appear to that certain dot. The images can help me explain what is my problem:
[image: First image]
[image: Second image]
As you can see, It is displaying like that, but I just need the information that is in Red to be displayed in each block.

This is a part of how I store the date:

```
if ($resultCheck > 0)
      {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
          $horario = (date('H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias']))));    

          $tempo[] = explode(',', $horario);

          $geral = $geral .'"'.(date('d/m/y', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])))). '",';
        }
      }

      $labels = trim($geral, ",");
```

This is my chart:

```
<script>
    var lbl = [<?php echo $labels; ?>];
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById('mychart1');

    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx1, {
        type: 'line', 
        data: {
          labels: lbl,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Corrente 1",
              data: [
                <?php 
                echo $datacor1;  
                ?>
              ],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'red',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
              label: "Corrente 2",
              data: [<?php echo $datacor2; ?>],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'blue',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
              label: "Corrente 3",
              data: [<?php echo $datacor3; ?>],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'green',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
              label: "Corrente Total",
              data: [<?php echo $datatotcor; ?>],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'black',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
          ]            
        },
        plugins: [

        ],
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                display: false
              }
            }]
          },

          title: {
            display: true,
            fontSize: 20,
            text: "Gráfico das Correntes"
          },

          labels: {
            fontStyle: "bold",
          },

          layout: {
            padding: {
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0
            }
          },
          tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            titleFontFamily: "'Arial'",
            titleFontSize: 14,
            titleFontStyle: 'bold',
            titleAlign: 'center',
            titleSpacing: 4,
            titleMarginBottom: 10,
            bodyFontFamily: "'Mukta'",
            bodyFontSize: 14,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: 'grey',
            callbacks:{
                title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
                },
                afterTitle: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                  return '<?php print_r($tempo[$mudarHorario][0]);?>';                   

                },
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                      var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';                  
                      if (label) {
                          label += ': ';
                      }
                      label += (tooltipItem.yLabel)+"A";                  
                      return label;
                }              
            }
          },
          aspectRatio: 1,
          maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
    });
    </script>
```

You can see in the callback the code that I've used to try to display the array.

Just tried using a new code to loop throw the tooltip, didn't work thought:

```
callbacks:{
                title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
                },
                afterTitle: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                  return '<?php print_r($tempo[$mudarHorario][0]);?>';                   

                },
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                      var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';                  
                      if (label) {
                          label += ': ';
                      }
                      label += (tooltipItem.yLabel)+"A";                  
                      return label;
                }
```